# DateTimeFormatter throws DateTimeParseException for date string

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time

The following code is throwing a DateTimeParseException:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.parse(
               "2019-01-01",
                formatter.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
        )
```

It also throws an exception with

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.parse(
               "2019-01-01",
                formatter)
        )
```

As does

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.parse(
                   "2019-01-01",
                    formatter)
            )
```

The `SimpleDateFormat` parser works just fine however -- I'm debating using it instead even though it's not thread safe and (I believe?) scheduled to be deprecated.

Obviously I'd prefer to use the java.time API, but I can't get this thing to work even after following the documented examples online. What do I do?

Comment: I would suspect that a `ZonedDateTime` also needs a time part ,

Comment: `ZonedDateTime dt = LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01", formatter).atTime(LocalTime.of(0,0,0)).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))`

Comment: Why do you think that you want a `ZonedDateTime`? For a date use `LocalDate`. For at date and time in UTC use `Instant` or if you insist, `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 4):

A `ZonedDateTime` must contain a date and a time; your input, `2019-01-01`, contains only a date.

For that reason, you should use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) in conjunction with [`LocalDate#atTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#atTime(int,int,int)) (to get a `LocalDateTime` object) and [`LocalDateTime#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone(java.time.ZoneId)) (with `ZoneOffset.UTC` to get a `ZonedDateTime`).

---

```
var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
var zonedDateTime = LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01", formatter)
                             .atTime(1, 2, 3) // (hours, minutes, seconds)
                             .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

The value of `zonedDateTime` is:

```
2019-01-01T01:02:03Z
```

Answer (score 0):

`ZoneDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` always expect pair values of date and time. If you do not have time value, but have to build `ZoneDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` instance then you can choose some default time value like `'00:00'` and proceed as follow:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01", formatter), LocalTime.MIN, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01", formatter), LocalTime.MIN);
```

**NOTE:** `java.time.LocalTime` has some useful time constants 
`MIN`('00:00'), `MAX`('23:59:59.999999999'), `MIDNIGHT`('00:00'), `NOON`('12:00')